# Why nav-title-slide-ios7 doesn't works with align-title="left"?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have an animation issue when I use `nav-title-slide-ios7 class` with `align-tittle="left"`. When is center aligned it works ok, but when is left aligned it flashes when making the animation.

http://codepen.io/asdasd3333/pen/Ixgpn

```
<ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive" align-title="left">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: try after removing text-align:center style form .bar .title {} class because styles flows from top to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try after removing text-align:center style form

```
.bar .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 43px;
    /* text-align: center; */ /** remove this **/
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 44px;
}
```

because styles flows from top to bottom it will work fine

**EDIT**

here is the link of codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKulD

Comment: I've changed it, and doesn't work for me. Could you modify my codepen to give me an example? Maybe I'm dismissing something Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, and there is no an elegant solution that modify the ionic css directly? I've tried this `text-align: left !important;` but doesn't works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by changing the animation that is set for the `ion-nav-view` to match that of the `ion-nav-bar` resolves the issue of the flashing during the transition animation.

```
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right-ios7"></ion-nav-view>
```

You can see the change on this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hIFys.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But I still see the same issue in your codepen. When the page transition ends, the tittle stay center aligned for a moment.